# sharing constant between packages in golang

Tags: go

I’ve the following code which require multiple packages in `cmd` package

```
PATH_SEP = string(os.PathSeparator)
```

my project structure is like following

```
go/src/my proj
-cmd
--runners
--otherpackage
-- package2
-- constants
--….
```

in constants i put the code

```
PATH_SEP = string(os.PathSeparator)
const2 etc
```

and in runners and package2/3 etc I use this constant.

is it OK ? otherwise I need to duplicate the code for other packages .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to declare struct with constant fields and import that struct in any package you wants to use the constants.

```
package cmd
type Constants struct{
    const1 int
    const2 int
}
```

It would be better to have a separate file for constants. Create a file called global.go which contains all constant structs to be used in different packages that way your code would be cleaner.

**Note:** We require constants to be shared in multiple files, so it will be better to import the package containing constants. Rather than package containing methods and other details even if we do not need them.

Comment: Thanks, my `main.go` file is in the same level of the ‘cmd’ ‘vendor`folders  etc, where you suggest to put the global.go const ?

Comment: At same level as `main.go` just make the struct exportable to export the variables.

Comment: thanks, it will be great if you can provide link to some git repo which follow this pattern. Thanks!

Comment: ok create a folder config which would contains a file. For more information on project layout Look at [Project Layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout)

Comment: you mean creating a file with structs under config ? any refernace please?

Comment: I have mentioned a reference in my comments for project layout. Also there is a reason I am using a separate file Checkout my edited answer.

Comment: This method would require to initialize the Constant struct right ? and the initialized object are to be exposed ?? that doesn't seem efficient...
thoughts ??

Comment: No you need not to initialize anything. Take a go tour. Go lang not works like other OOP. There are no objects.

Comment: hmmm but yet this confuses me a bit. you still have to do `c := Constants{const1:10, const2:100}` right ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constants as you describe, there is nothing wrong with it. But it is less intuitive.

How i would go about this is having a root package `constants` and those can be used anywhere in the project.

```
go/src/my proj
-cmd
-constants
--runners
--otherpackage
--package2
--….
```

Comment: What does your constants package contain? Is it a struct or just a bunch of exported vars? Can you include an example please.